# Call void only once with Accelerometer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have my code set up so my application is constantly looping through the accelerometer data in order to determine the position the phone is in. I want to be able to take the Z coordinates of the phone and call an action based on them.

Right now I have this:

```
if (.3 > filter.z && filter.z > -.3){
        NSLog(@"STRAIGHT = %f", filter.z);


    }
    else if (1.3 > filter.z && filter.z > .7){
        NSLog(@"DOWN = %f", filter.z);
         [self performSelector:@selector(loadNextFlag) withObject:nil
                  afterDelay:1.0];
    }
    else if (-.4 > filter.z && filter.z > -1.3){
          NSLog(@"UP = %f", filter.z);
    }
```

This code works. It knows what direction the phone is facing and logs the information correctly. What doesn't work is the performSelector. Since the accelerometer is constantly refreshing its coordinate info when I tilt my phone down it calls the performSelector action a large amount of times within seconds causing the app to crash. Does anyone know of a way I can call the action only once every time I tilt my phone downwards, while still keeping track of the the Z coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I worked it out. I added a boolean value called:

```
BOOl isPaused;
```

This allowed me to only call the action every new time I tilted my phone downwards. So like this:

```
 if (.3 > filter.z && filter.z > -.3){
        NSLog(@"STRAIGHT = %f", filter.z);
        isPaused = NO;

    }
    else if (1.3 > filter.z && filter.z > .7 && !isPaused){
        NSLog(@"DOWN = %f", filter.z);
        [self performSelector:@selector(submitGuess:) withObject:nil
                  afterDelay:0.2];
        isPaused = YES;
    }
    else if (-.4 > filter.z && filter.z > -1.3){
          NSLog(@"UP = %f", filter.z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multithreading to keep tracking the changes while updating the main (or any other) thread every once in a while using GCD's `dispatch_async`. In the following example, you will be sampling the data on a background thread but calling loadNextFlag only once every 20 samples:

```
__block int sampleCount = 0;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NULL), ^{
    if (.3 > filter.z && filter.z > -.3){
        NSLog(@"STRAIGHT = %f", filter.z);


    }
    else if (1.3 > filter.z && filter.z > .7){
        NSLog(@"DOWN = %f", filter.z);
        if (sampleCount >= 20) {
            sampleCount = 0;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self loadNextFlag];
            });
        } else {
            sampleCount++;
        }
    }
    else if (-.4 > filter.z && filter.z > -1.3){
        NSLog(@"UP = %f", filter.z);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually solved it by adding a Boolean value that pauses the Accelerometer when tilted downwards then resumes the accelerometer info when tilted straight again. So it will only call the action one time for every tilt down.